# check device width using jquery and get result back into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

I need to limit number of images displayed on first when loading the page. This function should only available in mobile view.

To do that, I need to check device width using `jQuery`and then get the result back into my `php` file.

Then using if statement inside a loop, I can limit the number of items displayed at once. If user needs to see all images, I added link at the bottom to load images as normal, without limiting.

How can I do this?

basically the idea I have now is, I have a variable in php (like boolean value to check isMobile true/false). I can assign value(true/false) from the output of `jQuery` code. I should send some data to jquery from here.(should I)?

I check device width using `jQuery`, send the result into my php file, then write the condition.

How can I achieve this?

**How can I check device width in `jQuery` and get the value into `php`?**

Comment: Maybe it is better to use `@media` query and hide all images except first N ones for small screens?

Comment: Please be aware of increasing chances to give you correct and precise answer – share you code, give steps to reproduce or/and test cases/data will increase your chances to get an good answer soon

Comment: @Flying i need to show a button to view more and i need to add that option i mentioned in my question. Im implementing this in magento

Comment: @Joey it can be achieved by putting additional CSS class (e.g. `.show-all`) to images container and force all images to be displayed when this class is available

Comment: @Flying how can i use it with php?

Comment: @Joey there is nothing to do with PHP, it should be done on client side. `$('.my-trigger-button').on('click', function(){$('.my-images-container').addClass('show-all')})`. And related CSS styles to display first N images without this class and all images if this class is available

Comment: @Flying it should be display only six images at first. that's the part I need to do here. to display all images, I use the button to show all images, I've implemented that. need to do is, limit number of images displayed at first

Comment: @Joey take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how it may look like (try to reduce window size to 640px max). As you can see - there is no need to detect device or to use server side code to achieve your goal.

```js
$('.show-all-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.images-list').toggleClass('show-all');
});
```

```css
.images-list .image {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.show-all-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; 
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .show-all-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .images-list:not(.show-all) .image {
    display: none;
  }
  .images-list:not(.show-all) .image:nth-child(1),
  .images-list:not(.show-all) .image:nth-child(2),
  .images-list:not(.show-all) .image:nth-child(3),
  .images-list:not(.show-all) .image:nth-child(4)
  {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images-list">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=1">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=2">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=3">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=4">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=5">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=6">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=7">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=8">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=9">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=10">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=11">
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=12">
</div>
<button class="show-all-button">Show all images</button>
```